# Resolve path tsconfig have problem with nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, tsconfig

I use NestJS 6.12.9 and Typescript 3.6.3. I have file tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths":{
      "@Models/*":["src/database/entities/*"],
      "@Commons/*":["src/common/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

in file jwt.service.ts, I have code:

```
import { User } from "@Models/user.entity";
```

when I run `npm run start:dev`, it builds into javascript and import { User } from "@Models/user.entity" is

```
const user_entity_1 = require("../../../../../../../D:\\Project\\MyJob\\Backend\\src\\database\\entities\\user.entity");
```

and error appears:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '../../../../../../../D:\Project\MyJob\Backend\src\database\entities\user.entity'ntity'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
>       at Object. (D:\Project\MyJob\Backend\dist\shared\auth\jwt.service.js:25:23)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

It only runs when I use:

```js
const user_entity_1 = require("../..\\database\\entities\\user.entity");
```

Answer (score 2):

i had same issue in nestjs and solved that issue like this...look at the image

[image]